# How to set then retrieve variables by rerunning the script script?

Tags: shell-script

I am running a script where I want to set variables through running a script.

script.sh

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# Check if passed parameters
if [[ -n $1 && -n $2 ]]; then
    export USER="$1"
    export PASS="$2"
fi
echo $USER $PASS
```

when I run this everything works as expected:

```bsh
root@master:/src#./script.sh root root
root root
```

But when I want to retrieve the variables running script without parameters I get nothing

Answer (score 0):

Since the script we are running is a child process of the current command line env and that's what prevented the script from storing those variables for future use.

So I have actually solved that by running:

```bsh
. ./script.sh root root
```